# Do you always must check for bad_alloc whenever dynamically allocating memory?

Tags: c++, exception, bad-alloc

If new cannot find enough memory, it throws an exception. Do I absolutely always need to check for that? I never did that and had no issues, but now I've read you should do that. Or only in certain cases?

```
try
{
    pPos = new Vector2D(5,1);
}
catch(bad_alloc)
{
    // NO MEMORY!
}
```

Comment: Depends on whether you can recover from lack of memory. Most of the time, no.

Comment: You can catch `bad_alloc` and ask the user to [download more RAM](https://downloadmoreram.com/),

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special about `bad_alloc`, you can catch it or not as you would any other exception.  It is *unusual* to catch it.  You would only do that if you had some way to recover from the out-of-memory condition.  But I think programs that are designed to deal with out-of-memory errors more commonly use the `nothrow` version of `new` instead:

```
pPos = new (std::nothrow) Vector2D(5,1);
if (!pPos) {
    // NO MEMORY!
}
```